# how to rewrite url on username calling from url directly

Tags: php, .htaccess

I want to call the profile page the same way facebook does it.
example.com/johndoe
This link should show me the profile page of John Doe, However I tried to get things well, but couldn't.

```
RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9]+)$ profile.php?username=$1 [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ /profile.php?username=$1 [L]
```

This should retreive the username and rewrite the url back using the profile.php

```
$username = $_GET['username'];
```

and this HTACCESS code doesn't run as expected.

Answer (score 0):

Use it like this,

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)$ profile.php?username=$1 [L]
```